How to write a user-defined function to get the latest non-null value of a column?
Currently, I have code like this:
WITH
  foo AS (
    SELECT 1 AS a, "hello" AS b, NULL AS c, 10 AS some_timestamp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, NULL, "world", 11
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, "hi", "!", 99
  )
SELECT
  a,
  ANY_VALUE(b HAVING MAX if(b is null, null, some_timestamp)) AS latest_b,
  ANY_VALUE(c HAVING MAX if(c is null, null, some_timestamp)) AS latest_c
FROM
  foo
GROUP BY
  a

The lines with ANY_VALUE are quite repetitive. Is there a way to abstract this logic away, maybe with a UDF?
In the end, it would be awesome if I could replace
  ANY_VALUE(b HAVING MAX if(b is null, null, some_timestamp)) AS latest_b,
  ANY_VALUE(c HAVING MAX if(c is null, null, some_timestamp)) AS latest_c

with something like that:
  latest_non_null(b, some_timestamp) AS latest_b,
  latest_non_null(c, some_timestamp) AS latest_c


You can create a custom user-defined aggregation function (UDAFs), currently in preview:
CREATE OR REPLACE AGGREGATE FUNCTION `project.dataset.latest_non_null`(
  value STRING,
  some_timestamp INTEGER)
RETURNS STRING
AS (
  ANY_VALUE(value HAVING MAX if(value is null, null, some_timestamp))
);

SELECT
  a,
  project.dataset.latest_non_null(b, some_timestamp) AS latest_b,
  project.dataset.latest_non_null(c, some_timestamp) AS latest_c,
FROM
  foo
GROUP BY
  a

Output:


Awesome, thanks! Do you know if it's possible to have a generic version of this, i.e., one that does not require value to be a fixed type (STRING in this example)?

I dont think so, the type of the parameter is required
